# Add record in ZOHO API

Tags: php, api, curl, zoho

I am trying to add a record (contact) to the ZOHO database using their API after submitting an order.

This requires an authorization token with a validity of 60 minutes which I can generate with a grant token, but which I can only generate with user interaction (GET). Is there a way to get a grant token without user interaction?

Maybe I'm just stupid, but why does adding a record to my ZOHO database require interaction from the user who orders my product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I'm just stupid, but why does adding a record to my ZOHO database require interaction from the user who orders my product.

No, ZOHO requires a token from a third-party resource (your site, application, etc.). Since all records are stored and processed on ZOHO servers, access to it must be controlled.

ZOHOs give a SDK, what help refresh token automatically.
Maybe [this](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/php-sdk/initialize.html) and [this](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/zoho-crm-permanent-access-token) help you

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me right direction. I wrote my own authorization class which is much simplier but i don't need much. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: I am glad to help you. Сlose the question now)